# What is required to authenticate user against RADIUS server

Tags: dd-wrt, radius, captive-portal

I am trying to build a captive portal for my wireless network. For the captive portal, I will be using a linksys router flashed with dd-wrt firmware (with chillispot).

For the authentication, I will be using an external LAMP stack with FREERADIUS with user data stored in a MySQL database.

I would be using this RADIUS server for multiple wireless networks at different locations. Now, my doubt is, how will the RADIUS server differentiate between different networks. Is "NAS ID" used for this?

I don't know how RADIUS authenticates a user. Will the NAS ID be taken into account?

For example, I have the following user in my database.

```
username: user1
password: password1
```

And I have three wireless networks at different locations, all of which will be authenticating against the single RADIUS server, eg:

```
Network 1
Network 2
Network 3
```

So when a user opens his browser, it will be taken to a login page. If the user enters the above user credentials, will he be given access irrespective of which network he is logged into? Obviously I don't want that to happen. I want to be able to add users with specific locations from where they can login.